# TRIGGER FUNCTION: With UPDATE of geom: Calculate automatically area column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, area, update, trigger

I'm using PostGIS and I would like to use trigger to: when there is a change in the geometry of a polygon, that its surface is also updated.

I have tested several syntaxes but I always get an error "ERROR: syntax error at the end of the entry" or nothing happens.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the error you receive.  Sample input data is also necessary, and making it a reproducible example by providing the full CREATE TABLE, CREATE FUNCTION, and CREATE TRIGGER syntax would increase the likelihood of generating a response.

Comment: I think you are a `END IF` short

Answer (score 4):

Your trigger set-up is bound to fail for a multitude of reasons, most prominently:

- a `[BEFORE|AFTER] INSERT` trigger **never** resolves to `TG_OP = 'UPDATE'`
- an **unbounded** `UPDATE` inside the function **will update the whole table**

Your attempt can be heavily simplified to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.burn_area()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  AS
  $FUNCTION$
    BEGIN
      NEW.area = ST_Area(NEW.geom)/10000;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $FUNCTION$
;

CREATE TRIGGER auto_burn_area
  BEFORE UPDATE OF geom ON schema."burn"      -- trigger only if geom is part of the UPDATE targets
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ( NOT ST_Equals(OLD.geom, NEW.geom) )  -- likely no performance gain even with an equal geometry as UPDATE value, but here for reference 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.burn_area()
;
```

---

As of PostgreSQL 12 you can use the [`GENERATED` column definitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) for an auto-updated read-only field (with some restrictions):

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ADD COLUMN area_calc FLOAT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( ST_Area(geom)/10000 ) STORED
;
```

Values generated from simple intra-row calculations which will never participate in filter conditions or joins are a good fit for dynamic (and lazy) evaluation, e.g. this approach or as part of a *View*.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
So if I understand correctly, in order to make updates in my function, my trigger must have a "before update"? I don't want the update trigger is activated on the whole table. Once it works, I would like to do insertions of values and not just updates in my trigger function.  So my trigger will have to be a "before insert or update" and not just a "before update" so the solution proposed would not work anymore.

Comment: @Demonshine you can simply add a *second* trigger on `BEFORE INSERT` executing the same function. I suggest to use the `GENERATED` approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ian Turton pointed out, you haven't ended both your if statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.burn_area()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$

BEGIN

IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
  IF (ST_Equals(NEW.geom, OLD.geom)=FALSE) THEN
    UPDATE "burn" SET area = st_area(NEW.geom)/10000;
  END IF;
END IF;

RETURN NEW; 
END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right @jbalk. I don't have any more errors but nothing happens when I execute my trigger. If I change the geom of my polygon, I still have the old value of my area and not the new.